# Example communicating with HandlerThread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-handler, android-handlerthread

I want to set up a HandlerThread from the GUI thread. Then some time later, when a button is clicked on the GUI, it runs callHello(), which then send a message to a HelloLogger object residing on the non-GUI thread which asynchronously logs "Hello World". I have tried a number of things, some block indefinitely, some never receive the message, etc etc. The code below is more or less as close as I have got, please could someone modify it to work?

```
public class HandlerThreadExample {

    private MyHandlerThread mMyHandlerThread;
    private Looper mLooper;
    private Handler mHandler;

    public HandlerThreadExample(){
        mMyHandlerThread = new MyHandlerThread();
        mMyHandlerThread.start();
        mLooper = mMyHandlerThread.getLooper();
    }
    public void callHello() {
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
    }
    private class MyHandlerThread extends HandlerThread {
        private HelloLogger mHelloLogger;
        private Handler mHandler;
        public MyHandlerThread() {
            super("The MyHandlerThread thread", HandlerThread.NORM_PRIORITY);
        }
        public void run (){
            mHelloLogger = new HelloLogger();
            mHandler = new Handler(getLooper()){
                public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                    mHelloLogger.logHello();
                }
            };
            super.run();
        }
    }
    private class HelloLogger {
        public HelloLogger (){
        }
        public void logHello(){
            Log.d("HandlerThreadExample", "Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

Best examples found:

- [HandlerThread Test](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/tests/coretests/src/android/os/HandlerThreadTest.java.shtml%20%22HandlerThread%20test)
- [How to create a Looper thread, then send it a message immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838207/how-to-create-a-looper-thread-then-send-it-a-message-immediately)
- [Async calls with Handler](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxQ1NHASJ41XL9/Making-Asynchronous-Calls-with-Handler)
- [HandlerThread vs Executor - When is one more appropriate over the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462098/handlerthread-vs-executor-when-is-one-more-appropriate-over-the-other)
- [Best use of HandlerThread over other similar classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149964/best-use-of-handlerthread-over-other-similar-classes)
- [Android HandlerThread](http://stephendnicholas.com/archives/42)
- [HandlerThread examples](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.os.HandlerThread)
- [Android: Passing data between main and worker threads](http://techtej.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/android-passing-data-between-main.html)
- [Java Synchronised](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html)
- [Sending messages between threads using activity thread queue and Handler class](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=921&title=Sending%20messages%20between%20threads%20using%20activity%20thread%20queue%20and%20Handler%20class)
- [Intro to Loopers and Handlers](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/)
- [developer.android: Specifying the Code to Run on a Thread](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/define-runnable.html)

At least now I can close the damned tabs

**Solution courtesy of help from pskink**

```
public class HandlerThreadExample2 {
    private static int MSG_START_HELLO = 0;
    private static int MSG_HELLO_COMPLETE = 1;
    private HandlerThread ht;
    private Handler mHtHandler;
    private Handler mUiHandler;
    private boolean helloReady = false;
    public HandlerThreadExample2(){
        ht = new HandlerThread("The new thread");
        ht.start();
        Log.d(App.TAG, "UI: handler thread started");
        mUiHandler = new Handler(){
            public void handleMessage(Message msg){
                if (msg.what == MSG_HELLO_COMPLETE){
                    Log.d(App.TAG, "UI Thread: received notification of sleep completed ");
                    helloReady = true;              }
            }
        };
        mHtHandler = new Handler(ht.getLooper()){
            public void handleMessage (Message msg){
                if (msg.what == MSG_START_HELLO){
                    Log.d(App.TAG, "handleMessage " + msg.what + " in " + Thread.currentThread() + " now sleeping");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Log.d(App.TAG, "Woke up, notifying UI thread...");
                    mUiHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_HELLO_COMPLETE);
                }
            }
        };
    }
    public void sendLongHello(){
        if (helloReady){
            Log.d(App.TAG, "sending hello " + Thread.currentThread());      
            mHtHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_START_HELLO);
            helloReady = false;
        } else {
            Log.e(App.TAG, "Cannot do hello yet - not ready");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Think you can do that in 4 lines of code using https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: Very interesting, thank you, will look into that another time. +1. But I think I should walk before I run

Comment: No problem but to be completely honest I gave up on using Handlers and Messages even though I have been writing a lot of Android code. No need to do it complicated when it can be done very simple, readable and maintainable IMO :)

Comment: Lord knows, I know where you're coming from!!!! Something tells me this is going to be a bounty question lol

Comment: 1) create a new HandlerThread,  2) start() it,  3) create a new Handler. using ht.getLooper() as a Looper parameter,  4) send a Message

Comment: @cYrixmorten Handlers and Messages are used by android code very often,  in fact Messages play fundamental role in the android event handling via a Looper

Comment: @pskink Not arguing against that at all. It is just simpler and much easier to maintain using EventBus, I think.

Comment: @pskink, AFAIK I already tried that, and played about with it and even then no luck, there are so many things that can be gotten wrong, I desperately need a full working example :(

Comment: @Jodes see my answer below

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This is a working example:

```
HandlerThread ht = new HandlerThread("MySuperAwesomeHandlerThread");
ht.start();
Handler h = new Handler(ht.getLooper()) {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleMessage " + msg.what + " in " + Thread.currentThread());
    };
};
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Log.d(TAG, "sending " + i + " in " + Thread.currentThread());
    h.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(i, 3000 + i * 1000);
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Make two class fields:

```
Handler mHtHandler;
Handler mUiHandler;
```

and try this:

```
HandlerThread ht = new HandlerThread("MySuperAwsomeHandlerThread");
ht.start();
Callback callback = new Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "got a meaasage in " + Thread.currentThread() + ", now sleeping... ");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "woke up, notifying ui thread...");
            mUiHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
        } else
        if (msg.what == 1) {
            Log.d(TAG, "got a notification in " + Thread.currentThread());
        }
        return false;
    }
};
mHtHandler = new Handler(ht.getLooper(), callback);
mUiHandler = new Handler(callback);
mHtHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 3000);
```

You can of course get rid of `Callback` interface and create two Handlers with overridden `handleMessage` method...

Comment: +1, thank you. I have edited my question, adding an example which attempts to integrate your answer. I still don't know how the GUI thread can tell when the worker thread has finished an operation (without blocking, obviously). What do I need to add to have helloComplete() called? Do I need to make/get another Handler somewhere?

Comment: @pskink can you possibly explain how the callback and looper run in parallel, is it to do with some form of scheduler?

Comment: @Chris the best way of learning that is to run my second snippet of code

Comment: How do you expect this to work? start() is non-blocking, so getLooper() in next line may return null.

Comment: @YaroslavMytkalyk no, it cannot, read `HandlerThread#getLooper` documentation

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are seeing is because your outer class is using a private mHandler field and so does your HandlerThread. The outer class' field is not initialized. You don't need the inner mHandler. The outer class can crate a handler from the looper you grab right after calling start().