# getLooper() returns null after started HandlerThread

Tags: android, android-handler, android-looper, android-handlerthread

I have an class extends `HandlerThread`, it looks like this:

```
public class MyHandlerThread extends HandlerThread {

  private Object lock;

  //constructor
  public MyHandlerThread() {
     super(“MyHandlerThread”);
     lock = new Object();
  }

  public void prepare() {
     //starts the handler thread
     start();

     //Wait for thread starting
     Log.d(TAG, "wait for thread starting…");
     synchronized (lock) {
        try {
            lock.wait(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to wait for thread to start");
        }
     }

     //WHY getLooper() returns null here?
     if(getLooper() == null) {
         Log.d("GET LOOPER NULL!");
     }
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    Log.d("run() begin...");
    initializeSomeObjects()
    Log.d(“initialise objects done!”);

    //Notify that run() finished
    synchronized (lock) {
       lock.notify();
    }
    Log.d("run() end!”);
  }

}
```

As you see above, the `prepare()` function starts the thread & wait for `run()` to be finished, then try to get looper.

In another class, I create an instance of `MyHandlerThread` & start it:

```
MyHandlerThread myThread = new MyHandlerThread();
myThread.prepare();
```

Logs showing in console:

```
wait for thread starting…
run() begin...
initialise objects done!
run() end!
GET LOOPER NULL!
```

Why in `prepare()` function, call to `getLooper()` returns **null** though the thread is already started (`run()` is executed)?

Comment: 1) create a new `HandlerThread`: `HandlerThread ht = new HandlerThread("foo");` 2) start it 3) make a `Handler`: `Handler h = new Handler(ht.getLooper()) {...` 4) send `Message`s: `h.sendEmptyMessage(999)`

Comment: Thanks, I found the same thing in google, but why with my approach `getLooper()` is NULL? My code looks like doing the same steps, only difference is I start the thread inside the class.

Comment: there are really 3 steps to make `Handler` / `HandlerThread` ready and one to set `Message`s... why make it harder? why do you want to extend `HandlerThread` ?

Comment: I really want to know the reason behind. It is a way to understand what is happening underneath, isn't it? Simply get it work is not my point, that's why I say I found your suggestion with google as well.

Comment: so if you want to know what is underneath then look [here](http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/HandlerThread.java)

Comment: and here is my answer for a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25096981/2252830

Comment: btw if yiu only want to do some action (`initializeSomeObjects`) in a calling thread do it in `prepare` before starting the `HandlerThread` and if you want to do that in background thread simply override `onLooperPrepared` which is called right before `Looper.loop()` is called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HandlerThread` `Looper` is initialized in `HandlerThread#run()`.

If you override the method and don't call `super.run()`, the init code from superclass is not executed.

Comment: not really: `getLooper()` method returns a `Looper` that is associated with this `HandlerThread`, btw he is calling it from a UI thread and UI thread does have a `Looper`, doesn't if?

Comment: @pskink Thanks, overlooked the fact that it was `HandlerThread#getLooper()` and not e.g. `Looper#myLooper()`. Answer rewritten.