# How to run a looper in addition to an infinite loop

Tags: java, android, android-handler, android-looper

I've got separate thread that is running an infinite loop, which also updates the main ui thread via a handler (my thread > handler > ui thread).

Infinite loop on second thread:

```
while (true) {
  Thread.sleep(100);
  // do xyz
}
```

However I now would like to modify some objects within the thread VIA the main UI thread.

If I create an additional handler to work in the opposite direction (ui thread > handler > my thread) , I would need to run a looper and my infinite loop at the same time - how do I achieve this? Where do I call the relevent`looper.loop()`?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25096981/2252830

Comment: @pskink I have read through and run the code in the answer you provided. However I still reach the same issue, how do I run the infinite loop on the second thread as well as the looper itself?

Comment: just use a `HandlerThread` as i have shown in my example, `HandlerThread` is a combination of a `Thread` and a `Looper`

Comment: from the `HandlerThread` docs: `'''Handy class for starting a new thread that has a looper. The looper can then be used to create handler classes. Note that start() must still be called.'''`