# Android handler, perform post() not in the ui thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-handler

From the beginning I though Handler's methods `post()` and `postDelayed()` did things in a different thread from UI thread, and I decided to create a TCP Socket on it, but it's not working.

I'm receiving `NetworkOnMainThreadException` was thrown.

Is there any ways to perform `post()` and `postDelayed()` tasks not in the UI thread?

```
public class ServerHandler extends Handler {

private Socket serverSocket;   

public ServerHandler(){
    super(new MyHandlerThread("MyHandlerThread").getLooper());
}

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    super.handleMessage(msg);
}

public void connectServer()
{
    post(serverConnection);
}

public void writeMessage(String msg){
    try {
        serverSocket.getOutputStream().write(msg.getBytes());
        Log.d("MyLog","Message sent!");
    }
    catch (IOException io){
        Log.d("MyLog","SendMessage error");
    }
}

private Runnable serverConnection = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            serverSocket = new Socket("152.168.21.24", 5001);

            Log.d("MyLog","Server connected!");

            while(true){
                Log.d("MyLog","Listening server");
                byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                int bytesReceived = serverSocket.getInputStream().read(buffer);
                if(bytesReceived==-1) {
                    throw new IOException("Server disconnected");
                }
                else {
                  String msg = new String(buffer,0,bytesReceived);
                  Log.d("MyLog","Message received: " + msg);

                }
            }
        }

        catch (IOException io){
            Log.d("MyLog","Server connection error " + io.getMessage());
            connectServer();
        }
    }
};
```

}

Comment: Use a broadcastreceiver. 100% it works.

Comment: You can also implement the `EventBus` library @ http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/ to simplify communication between UI, ASYNC and Background threads.

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Handler#post()` posts Messages and Runnables on `Looper` threads.  The default constructor of a `Handler` will bind itself to the Looper thread that it was created on. If it's not on a Looper thread, then it'll throw an exception.  So, to use a Handler on a worker thread, you must first create a thread and loop it with a [Looper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html). Then you pass the given `Looper` to the `Handler`'s constructor.

Fortunately, there's already a utility class that does most of the work for you. It's called [HandlerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html).  Just create a `HandlerThread`, and call `getLooper` whenever you need the Looper for the thread.

**EDIT**: Default Handler constructor does not choose the main thread.  It chooses the current thread if it's a Looper thread already.

Comment: Here's an example on using `HandlerThread` - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094330/example-communicating-with-handlerthread