# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException when getting data from mysql database (using PHP)

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to get data from database using mysql-php and insert them into a ListView- android
1-There is one title in database and even if I remove the while loop in php file I got the error below
2-How to handle if I have multiple results?

Here's my code

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_polls);
        ListView listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_polls);
        ArrayList<String> titles=new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> a=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles );
        listView.setAdapter(a);
        Handler handler=new Handler(this.getMainLooper());
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    titles.add(getPolls());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

and this is my method to connect with mysql

```
public String getPolls() throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.8/getPolls.php");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = r.readLine();
        return line;
    }
```

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysqli_select_db($con, "evote");

$qu="select * from polls";
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$qu)) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo $row['title'];
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

And here is the error I am getting:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.evote, PID: 21601
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.evote/com.example.evote.userPolls}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

And it also shows me an error on line of

```
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
```

Comment: In android, one cannot do network activity on the main (or UI) thread - it must be done in a separate thread.  See this android info on background work: https://developer.android.com/guide/background . See, impersistent work - the `ExecutorService` is likely where you'll end up.  Also many popular answers in SO for android are outdated -  solutions for NetworkOnMainThreadException is an example - AsyncTasks are deprecated so avoid the most popular answer when searching.  Note `handler.post` defers the work but still runs on UI/main thread given you are using the `MainLooper` - hence the error.

Comment: I tried to create a HandlerThread and then create a Handler to get his Looper instead og getMainLooper but I got the same result.. do you have any example of how use `ExecutorService` in this case?

Comment: I noticed from your edit history where you create a `HandlerThread` but you did not `.start()` it ?  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18844161/17856705 - I would try that first.  Otherwise the getLooper on the handler thread  would not work as expected

Comment: Aside from that, this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68522179/17856705 is a starting point on `ExecutorService`.

Comment: Whoever dup'ed the Q should note that the most popular A uses a deprecated solution.  And there are 65 alternate answers for someone to dig through.  Not too helpful.

Comment: The 'ExecutetorService` has worked :D , thank you very much, and yes all answers are about AsyncTasks.. Idk why the question is closed.